# Удаление файлов с ФТП

Tags: ftp

Удалил ***все*** файлы на FTP, а сайт до сих пор работает, что бы могло послужить этому? Хотя раньше когда удалял, то все моментально пропадало!

Comment: Может, ты не на том удалил)))

Comment: Бэкап то хоть есть?)))

Comment: Окей, почистил БД, все равно захожу на сайт и вижу свои данные.

Answer (score 1):

F5.

Comment: +1 обновить страницу поможет -_-